# Root expressions inside Eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I need the eigenvalues of this matrix as a function of Ny. When I tried whith a simpler matrix (4 x 4), it worked, but now, with this 25 x 25 matrix it returns what is shown in picture bellow:

[image]

The simpler case is:

```
MC={{2207.91 - 46027. Ny, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 3437.27 - 41761.9 Ny, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 31086.5 - 104682. Ny, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 35326.6 - 91922.4 Ny}}

EV[Ny_] = Eigenvalues[MC]
```

The output is:

```
{{2207.91 - 46027. Ny, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 3437.27 - 41761.9 Ny, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 31086.5 - 104682. Ny, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 35326.6 - 91922.4 Ny}}


{31086.5 - 104682. Ny, 35326.6 - 91922.4 Ny, 2207.91 - 46027. Ny, 
 3437.27 - 41761.9 Ny}
```

In this case, the eigenvalues are simply functions of Ny, as they should be, but in the other case, where I have the 25 x 25 matrix, I get these root expressions.

What I'm doing wrong? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what it is being asked. And without input it is hard to venture a guess. Are parametrized `Root` objects a point of concern?

Comment: Yes, I think so.